# Mutex lock inside another mutex lock

Tags: c, mutex

I dont know if it is a dummy question, but: is it a good practice to have a mutex lock inside a block with another mutex lock?

```
pthread_mutex_t lock1;
pthread_mutex_t lock2;
.
.
.
pthread_mutex_lock(&lock1);

//some code
pthread_mutex_lock(&lock2);

//some code

pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock2);

//some code

pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock1);
```

Comment: What would you be attempting to accomplish by having the second lock?

Comment: @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica the first lock is used in order to read the nodes of queue and the inside lock is used in order to delete some nodes of the queue

Comment: Since both mutexes protect the same resource, why not only have one?

Comment: It's not something that's inherently "good" or "bad".  There are cases where it may be the only reasonable way to do something, e.g. if you need to copy resource1 to resource2, and they are protected by lock1, lock2 respectively, then you need to take both locks; and since you can't take them simultaneously, one will necessarily be "inside" the other.  There may be other cases where a different approach would be better.

Comment: One thing to watch out for with such patterns is [lock inversion](http://www.lockexplorer.com/blog/2011/11/finding-lock-inversions-before-they-become-deadlocks.html).  If a different thread tries to take lock2 and then lock1, you can get a deadlock.

Comment: It sounds from your comment like maybe you would be better off with a [rwlock](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/806-6867/6jfpgdcnl/index.html).

Comment: Are these mutexes used only in this one block of code, or are they used from multiple places?